# Connection problem between PC and PBX machine

Tags: pbx

I encountered the error message “Error Opening Com Port” on PC. That PC is used for PBX System and PBX (Panasonic Digital Super Hybrid System KX-TD500 version 2.5) uses RS 232 serial interface for the connection with that PC.I already checked both 25-contact and 9-contact connectors and all are good conditions.
And I use Win Tariff Software for recording telephone calls and this software cannot record telephone calls since the above error appeared.
How do I solve this problem?
Anybody help me, please.
Thanks in advanced for your help.

Comment: I may be wrong -- I *hope* I am actually -- but I suspect this is one occasion where you might be better off asking the software vendor (Panasonic in this case?) for help. I think that the software you're talking about may be a little too obscure to get much help here.

Comment: Try contacting the person/company that did the installation for you. They will generally have the required expertise.

Answer (score 1):

The first steps in troubleshooting that problem are:

- Make sure the cable is connected to the SMDR port on the KX-TD500 and the correct COM port on the PC
- Turn the PC off and back on
- Try a different cable
- Try a different COM port on the PC (you will need to set the COM port in the software, too)
- Try a different PC
- Try connecting the cable to the PROG port on the KX-TD500 and see if you can communicate using the Maintenance Console software (e.g. download the system data report or view traffic information or system status)
- Reset the KX-TD500
- Power off the KX-TD500, remove and re-install the CPU card, power the system back on

Perform each of those steps in that order. After each step, try to see if communications is restored. The steps are ranked (approximately) by ease. Don't omit any of them even if you try them in a different order (stop, of course, if one reveals the source of the problem). I'm assuming that you've had this setup working properly before.

If those steps don't narrow down the source of the problem, then you may have a defective CPU card.

I have some experience with smaller Panasonic Hybrid systems, but no current access. I don't have any experience with Win Tariff.